# How to connect to a websocket using gorilla?

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I would like to see a minimal and simple example of how to connect to a websocket using gorilla.

The only example I found to connect to a websocket was [this](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/client.go),
but I couldn't understand it, and I couldn't find an explanation of how it works.

**Edit:**

Line 20:
Why did he keep the websocket address in `flag.String` instead of a variable string?

Line 26:
Does this part create a signal that will notify the program when the user presses crtl + C?

```golang
interrupt: = make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify (interrupt, os.Interrupt)
```

Line 32:
What does this line do?

```golang
websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial (u.String (), nil)
```

Line 60:
Because `[]byte(t.String())` instead of `t.string()`?

Comment: It would really help if you could add the exact part of the sample you don't understand to your question, and ask specific questions about it -- e.g. "what does the `done` channel do?", etc.

Comment: I had not understood anything about the code but with its explanation I was able to understand a good part, but there were some doubts, I will update the question

Comment: I've answered your specific questions at the end of my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample's `README` says:

> The client sends a message every second and prints all messages received.

Looking at the code, the latter part (prints all messages received) happens here:

```
go func() {
    defer close(done)
    for {
        _, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("read:", err)
            return
        }
        log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
    }
}()
```

This spins up a goroutine that reads messages from `c` (the websocket connection) in a loop and prints them out. It stops when the read fails, which happens for errors and when the connection is closed.

The main goroutine does this:

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
defer ticker.Stop()

for {
    select {
    case <-done:
        return
    case t := <-ticker.C:
        err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(t.String()))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write:", err)
            return
        }
    case <-interrupt:
        log.Println("interrupt")

        // Cleanly close the connection by sending a close message and then
        // waiting (with timeout) for the server to close the connection.
        err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, ""))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write close:", err)
            return
        }
        select {
        case <-done:
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
        }
        return
    }
}
```

It has a ticker firing every second, on which a message is sent to the websocket. When the reader goroutine is done it closes the `done` channel, which signals this loop with the `select` to exit too.

Finally, there's an "interrupt" selection to handle Ctrl+C, cleanly stopping the client.

---

To answer your specific questions:

Line 20: this flag enables you to set the address from the command line when executing the program, instead of it being hardcoded. You can call it like `client -addr localhost:9044` to set a different port, for example. See also https://gobyexample.com/command-line-flags

Line 26: yes this is for `Ctrl+C`; see also https://gobyexample.com/signals

Line 32: `DefaultDialer` is a [preconfigured](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#DefaultDialer) dialer in the `websocket` package. Per the documentation, it's equivalent to

```
var DefaultDialer = &Dialer{
    Proxy:            http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
    HandshakeTimeout: 45 * time.Second,
}
```

Line 60: [WriteMessage](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.WriteMessage) takes a `[]byte`, so you have to convert the string to a `[]byte`